# Desktop icon file path

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-xp, desktop

Is there any way to retrieve file path for item placed on desktop, which is under cursor?

Due desktop area is the listview, it is possible to get item index under cursor (ListView_GetHotItem macro), but how to retrieve item metainfo (file path)?

Unfortunately Win7 has changed file list container from ListView to some another undocumented implementation.

The goal is to perform some system actions if file path matches some rules and hide original tooltip.

Thanks

Comment: You use the IFolderView interface.

Comment: It is the main problem to get IFolderView interface. Getting it resolves my issue.

Comment: It [takes a few steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx). To get the desktop, use [`IShellWindows::FindWindowSW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836568(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `SWC_DESKTOP` flag. Why do you need this information anyway?

Comment: **Raymond Chen**, thanks a lot. But IShellWindows::FindWindowSW supports SWC_DESKTOP flag only for Vista and higher. And it is not clear what is PIDL of Desktop area (not desktop virtual folder). I had not found simple solution with Shell API, so I was enforced to implement some Shell extension (with IQueryInfo and IPersistFile).

Comment: It's not supported on Windows XP. The interface for getting this information was not added until Vista.